# Strings not comparing

Tags: c#

The decoded message what was first sent using sockets to another form cannot be compared or can be but that if doesn't work. That if was just jumped every time

```
byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
string data = encoder.GetString(receivedData);

listMessage.Items.Add("Friend: " + data);

if (data == "Friend Disconnected")
{
    //this not perform
    listMessage.Items.Clear();
    lblHostPort.Text = "";
    lblLocalPort.Text = "";
    grpFriend.Visible = true;
    grpHost.Visible = true;
    button1.Text = "connect";
}
```

Comment: Why are you allocating a 1500 byte array before immediately discarding it? Do you know all the data has been received before you convert it into a string? Do you have the right encoding? This question can't be answered without the value of `receivedData` and the encoding for `encoder`.

Comment: I am not clear on what your question is, and "C#" is not really enough of a hint as to the underlying technologies at work. Nor is "Strings not comparing" much of a problem statement. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Research "C# String comparisons" (google).  I am guessing something like this is what you may be looking for:  !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) && data.Contains("Friend Disconnected")

Answer (score 1):

String comparision only works if the strings are **exactly** the same. [An extra, missing or different whitespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2). A small letter where a big one should be. Even different [Unicode Normalisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringnormalizationextensions.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_StringNormalizationExtensions_Normalize_System_String_) - all of this and more can get in the way of it. As you are creating that string from raw bytes, even [different encodings](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) could throw a wrench into that mix.

As a general rule, string is terrible for processing and information transmissions. The only type somewhat worse is byte themself. The only advantage of string is that is (often) human readable.

But a numeric error code or even Enumeration tends to be leagues more reliable for this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

Their is 2 possibilities for you issues.

For the first one, maybe that you are not using the correct encoding in your encoder object. (difficult to say without additional information on this object.)

[Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8)

Something that you can try is to check if you can get better result by using the Compare method between strings instead of the operator ==.

You will then be able to perform comparison case insensitive or with specifics options.
Again, I can't give you more information right now as you don't indicate the content of the data variable in your question.

[string comparison method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_System_Globalization_CompareOptions_)